# Remove the string from URL

Tags: coldfusion

How to remove the string after last '/' from a URL?

Example: `<cfset normalURL = "http://test.com/myhome/live">`

Expected outcome: `http://test.com/myhome`

Comment: A combination of `replace`, `len`, `left`, and  `ListLast` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it.

```
<cfset normalURL = "http://test.com/myhome/live">
<cfoutput><p>#normalURL#</p></cfoutput>
```

Output from above code:

> `http://test.com/myhome/live`

```
<cfset stringAfterLastSlash = ListLast(normalURL,"/")>
<cfoutput><p>#stringAfterLastSlash#</p></cfoutput>
```

Output from above code:

> `live`

```
<cfset stringRemovedFromURL = Replace(normalURL,"/#stringAfterLastSlash#","")>
<cfoutput><p>#stringRemovedFromURL#</p></cfoutput>
```

Output from above code:

> `http://test.com/myhome`

[You can play with this code and see the results here](https://trycf.com/gist/e8481bfc5b75af3924cd7f8452341d4b/acf11?theme=monokai).